# What is the inverse of the integrated $\chi^2$ function?

Tags: probability-distributions, statistical-physics

I am implementing some preprocessing of variables in the context of a paper called [A Neural Bayesian Estimator for Conditional Probability Densities](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0402093).

It states: 1.) Given a non-linear, a monotonous variable transformation $F:t\rightarrow s$ such that $s$ is distributed uniformly is applied. 2.) Afterwards $s$ is scaled to lie between -1 and 1. 3.) Finally, the flat distributions need to be converted into Gaussian distributions, centered at zero with std 1. While the first two steps are clear, I am struggling with the third one.

Regarding 3.), the author further states that the inverse of the integrated $\chi^2$ function may be used.

**Update 1:**

After reading the paper again, it seems that $\chi^2$ doesn't directly relate to chi, but is rather calculated as follows:

$\chi^2$ = P*(1-o)^2+(1-p)*((-1)-o)^2

with `P` as the purity (can be computed easily given some variable) and `o` the variable itself.

For a given $s$ scaled to lie between -1 and 1, I may just calculated the integral with $lower bound=-1$ and $upper bound=s$ and then getting the inverse of it.

Question: How to do this numerically?

Comment: I'm having trouble in understanding what you are asking. Could you please be more specific? What is your difficulty regarding statement 3.) ?

Comment: Actually, the overall question is according to the title: What is the inverse of the integrated $\chi^2$ function?

Comment: Ah, right. My bad. Well, $\chi^2$ is zero at the origin and positive in $(0,+\infty)$ (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution), so $X(t)=\int^t_0\chi^2(s)\mathrm{d}s$ is strictly increasing with image $[0,1)$ and therefore its restriction to $(0,+\infty)$ has an inverse $X^{-1}:(0,1)\to(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: Got an update....

Comment: Just a small piece of advice: you'd do well to include the necessary definitions (specially non-standard ones) into your question so that people need not go through the paper to find them. For instance, if you just say $\chi^2$ without saying what it is, people working in probability and statistics will just assume as I did. You fixed this partially by writing $\chi^2$ as employed in the paper (which, by the way, was a very poor choice of notation by the authors in the context they work), but then you should include what you mean by purity in the context of the paper (formula (6)).